# Using android phone to debug

Tags: android

I have been experimenting with android apps using the android sdk with eclipse. So far i have only used the emulator, but i was planning on getting an android phone in the next week. my question is simple, will any android phone be able to plug into eclipse and help me test my application or are there only certain phones that are capable of this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes Infact debugging using device will be more better..

You can see the log events directly over Log Cat coming from device when connected to your computer via USB (Make Sure USB Driver of Your device is on Your Computer).

You Can Run Debugger As Well and can easily walk through the break Points that you will set in the code. Add debugging enabled true in Manifest File.

You can see the log cat event coming from your application without your computer as well. Download log cat application from Android Market. Install Your application and test your logs and all while testing in field.

In short Device Debugging is more preferred as ultimately application is to be deployed over it only. Simulator will never give such efficient results. And When Application involve hardware interaction like of GPS, Camera. We are left with no option.

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with any android phone.

Comment: thank you, i just wanted to make sure before i forked over the money to get one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. According to the Android Compatibility Document any Android devices must work with the Android Development Tools or they won't be certified.